# Sinon.js: cannot mock node.js net object

Tags: node.js, sockets, mocha.js, sinon

I am pretty new to testing so this question might be straightforward...but I still need some help:

I have a node.js server:

```
const net = require("net");
const Canvas = require("./canvas");

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const canvas = (new Canvas(socket));
  ...
});

server.listen(8124);
```

In the canvas.js file:

```
class Canvas {
  constructor(socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }
  
  disconnect() {
    this.socket.end();
    this.socket.destroy();
  }
}
```

I am trying to test the disconnect function, and trying to mock the methods for the socket object:

```
const Canvas = ...
const expect = require("expect");
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe('Canvas', () => {
  const fakeSocket = {
    end: () => {},
    destroy: () => {},
    write: () => {},
  };

  let canvasObj;
  const mock = sinon.mock(fakeSocket);

  beforeEach(() => {
    canvasObj = new Canvas(mock);
  });

  describe("disconnect", () => {
    it("calls the appropriate functions", () => {
      mock.expects("end").once();
      mock.expects("destroy").once();
      canvasObj.disconnect();
      mock.verify();
      expect(fakeSocket.end).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(fakeSocket.destroy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, when I run the test it says TypeError: this.socket.end is not a function. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 version of possible disconnect test scripts I can think of, when I see your example:

1. use sinon.fake(),

```js
// File: canvas.spec.js
const expect = require('expect');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const Canvas = require('./canvas');

describe('Canvas using sinon.fake()', () => {
  const fakeSocket = {
    end: sinon.fake(),
    destroy: sinon.fake(),
    write: sinon.fake(),
  };

  let canvasObj;

  beforeEach(() => {
    canvasObj = new Canvas(fakeSocket);
  });

  describe('disconnect', () => {
    it('calls the appropriate functions', () => {
      canvasObj.disconnect();
      // Note: You can not directly use toHaveBeenCalled() because this is from jest expect, not sinon.
      expect(fakeSocket.end.calledOnce).toBe(true);
      expect(fakeSocket.destroy.calledOnce).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

2. use sinon.mock()

```js
// File: canvas2.spec.js
const expect = require('expect');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const net = require('net');
const Canvas = require('./canvas');

describe('Canvas using sinon.mock()', () => {
  let canvasObj;
  const socket = new net.Socket();
  const mock = sinon.mock(socket);
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Note: Subject under test is socket, not mock.
    canvasObj = new Canvas(socket);
  });

  describe('disconnect', () => {
    it('calls the appropriate functions', () => {
      mock.expects('end').once();
      mock.expects('destroy').once();
      canvasObj.disconnect();
      mock.verify();
    });
  });
});
```

When I run it using mocha from terminal:

```
$ npx mocha *.spec.js


  Canvas using sinon.mock()
    disconnect
      ✔ calls the appropriate functions

  Canvas using sinon.fake()
    disconnect
      ✔ calls the appropriate functions


  2 passing (16ms)
```

Additional note: sinon expectation on [fake function / spy](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fakes/#when-to-use-fakes) been called once is: [calledOnce](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#spycalledonce) not [toHaveBeenCalled()](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalled).

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like I mixed up the syntax between sinon and jest a bit.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, then: please [vote or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).